# Cocos2d - json/document.h file not found

Tags: ios, json, cocos2d-js

I create a mobile game using cocos2d framework. The problem is I got this error when I try to compile ios platform.

```
In file included from /Users/MNurdin/Documents/Game/WTP/frameworks/js-bindings/bindings/manual/chipmunk/js_bindings_chipmunk_manual.cpp:26:
In file included from /Users/MNurdin/Documents/Game/WTP/frameworks/js-bindings/bindings/proj.ios_mac/../../cocos2d-x/extensions/cocos-ext.h:16:
In file included from /Users/MNurdin/Documents/Game/WTP/frameworks/js-bindings/bindings/proj.ios_mac/../../cocos2d-x/extensions/assets-manager/AssetsManager.h:32:
/Users/MNurdin/Documents/Game/WTP/frameworks/js-bindings/bindings/proj.ios_mac/../../cocos2d-x/extensions/assets-manager/Manifest.h:36:10: fatal error: 'json/document.h' file not found
#include "json/document.h"
```

I follow exactly this tutorial from A- Z. I run this command in my terminal to compile my project.

```
cocos compile -p ios
```

Reference: http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/html5/v2/cocos-console/en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only an issue if you are using the source code from github.
I assume you are missing extra step required when you got the project from github.

In ReadMe it says:

> ### Github note
>
> If you fork our github repository or download the package from github,
> you will need to do some extra tasks:
>
> - Run `frameworks/js-bindings/cocos2d-x/download-deps.py` to download external dependencies for Cocos2d-x
> - Run `tools/cocos2d-console/download-bin.py` to download bin files for some cocos2d-console plugins like Google Closure Compiler and JSC
>   Compiler.

Comment: For the latest version v3.6, you can execute "download-deps.py" to download and install dependencies to fix this problem.
$python download-deps.py

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the subproject is completely missing json/document.h file as referenced in Manifest.h.  I attempted a simple comment of the include, but this raised errors I believe related to the missing header.  I think filing a bug related to this subproject (Cocos2d_libs) is in order.